# Selecting Fields From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to write this query in rails other than by using the execute method?

```
connection.execute("select value_1, value_2, value_3 from table1 join table2 on table2.table1_id = table1.id where table2.table3_id = table3_id_value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far easier if you bend to the Rails conventions for pluralizing and capitalizing names.

Then if table1 is really `foos` and table2 is `bars` corresponding to Active Record `Foo` and `Bar`, declarations, you'd want

```
belongs_to :foo
```

in the `Bar` record.  This corresponds to a foreign key `foo_id`.  Then add matching

```
has_many :bars
```

in the `Foo` record. This allows retrieving all the `bars` records that reference `foo` with `foo.bars`.  With all this in place, the query would be

```
Foo.join(:bar).select(:value_1, :value_2, :value_3)
   .where('bars.table3_id = ?, table3_id_value)
```

It's possible to override the default conventions for table and foreign key names.  Look up the correct options in [the Active Record query documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select).

Comment: thanks for the tip! So I just ran a slightly modified version of your suggestion (had to add brackets around select values and an 's' to 'bar') and only two of the three select values were returned (one of the three is not from Foo). Any ideas?

Comment: The Active Record join interface does not allow access to the fields of the joined record.  You have to use one of the lower level calls.